# How to improve text recognition using Microsoft OCR?

Tags: c#, service, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I'm working with Microsoft OCR library, and I'd like to know if there is some way to improve the text recognition of my language. I ran a program with the OCR library and there is a poor detection of some words of the image I'm providing.

I already know that the OCR supports Spanish but it is not processing all the words correctly, for example:

[image: e.i.]

The response that I got in the json is:

```
    ...
         "boundingBox": "358,180,271,278",
         "lines": [
            {
               "boundingBox": "362,180,67,17",
               "words": [
                  {


             "boundingBox": "362,180,67,17",
                 "text": "Nonúre"
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "boundingBox": "358,208,118,22",
           "words": [
              {
                 "boundingBox": "358,208,63,22",
                 "text": "tlgcT2"
              },
              {
                 "boundingBox": "428,217,7,4",
                 "text": "-"
              },
              {
                 "boundingBox": "441,210,35,16",
                 "text": "ED6"
              }
           ]
        },
    ...
```

Identifies "**Nombre**" as "**Nonúre**" and "**CT2**" *(from CT2 - ED6)* as "**tlgcT2**"

Is there any way to improve the text recognition?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, you are using the OCR V1 and goes regular hehehe. You need to use the version 2 Check this URL [OCR V2](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc). Basically you need to do some changes on your URL.
I don't know why Microsoft is using the V1 to the default version maybe because it's and preview... But you can use it!
Now when you extaxt OCR Text or OCR Json the detection it will be better.

Example:
[Using OCR v2 with Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wVVD.png)

Please let me know if it's working for you.